# Get appsetting.json key,value from non controller class

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have connection variables stored in appsetting.json.  They are only used for a specific reporting engine.  It seems `IOptions<>` is injected automatically into the controller class, however, I'd rather not pass this connection via a controller.

So, currently...

My Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.Configure<DbContext>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
   services.Configure<CrystalContext>(Configuration.GetSection("CrystalConnection"));
   ...    
}
```

A controller initiation with POCO class `DbContext`:

```
private readonly BuildRepository _BuildRepository;

public BuildController(IOptions<DbContext> dbContext)
{
   _BuildRepository = new BuildRepository(dbContext.Value.DB1Connection, dbContext.Value.DB2Connection);
}
```

So, that's all fine and dandy, as my repository can reach the required databases.

However, another connection happens in a helper.  I'm not sure if this is the way to do it or now.  The report is CrystalReport, and it's settings are another POCO class.

```
public class CrystalContext
{
    public String Server { get; set; }
    public String Database { get; set; }
    public String UserId { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking I could just use `IOptions<>` again like

```
public MatterWIPHelper (IOptions<CrystalContext> context) 
{
    connection = context
}
```

However, it seems that is not the case as it's not direct injected on that class. I get an error

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'context' of
>   'MatterWIPHelper.MatterWIPHelper(IOptions)'

What is the right approach here?

UPDATE:
To confirm I can use `IOptions<CrystalContext>` in the controller.

```
private readonly BuildRepository_Repository;
private CrystalContext _CrystalContext;

public BuildController(IOptions<DbContext> dbContext, IOptions<CrystalContext> CrystalContext)
{
    _Repository = new BuildRepository(dbContext.Value.DB1Connection, dbContext.Value.DB2Connection);
    _CrystalContext = CrystalContext.Value;
}
```

Then I can pass the Context into my helper like

```
Report.helper(_CrystalContext).
```

This just doesn't seem like a good way to do it..

Comment: Does `CrystalContext`'s constructor takes parameters? make sure they are also register with DI

Comment: @LP13 added the POCO class. I imagined I would just pass in IOptions like a the controller.